# Why are there a lot of outliers after estimating kernel density?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers, kernel-density

I have a long numeric sequence of the following type:

```
>str(series)
[1] num [1:4739] 0 0 0.155 0.0625 0.0668 ...
```

In order to compute kernel density estimate of this series, I used `density` function by `stats` package:

```
d=density(series)
```

The estimated density values, `d$y`, is a sequence such that

```
> c(max(d$y), min(d$y), mean(d$y))
[1] 5.275045e+00 3.249637e-05 4.734156e-01
```

Its behaviour is depicted in the following figures:
[image]
and
[image]
From its boxplot:
[image]
I observed that there are a lot of outliers (above the maximum). My question is the following: why? Maybe I did something wrong in `d=density(series)`?

Comment: I'm not sure I see which outlier you are referring to. Note that the scale of the y values of your density aren't at all relayed to the observed values. That's just the range of the estimated probability function that integrates to 1 over your data domain. For example with `range(density(c(100:200))$y)` even though numbers are between 100 and 200, the range of the density y values never get over 0.001 (which is as expected)

Comment: @MrFlick I'm talking about red points above the red bar between 1 and 2 of the boxplot.

Comment: Outliers are defined by points 1.5 times the Interquartile range away from the median. I’m not sure that’s inconsistent with your density plot. It’s a bit confusing that you used index on the x axis rather than d$x so maybe that’s just altering your view of where your data lies.

Comment: I uploaded another pic, with d$x on the x axis

Comment: Well, it seems a bit odd that your density plot only goes up to 1 on the x-axis. Did you set the xlim or something? But as you can see most of the density lies around 0. It seems very unusual to have values greater than 1 so those are marked as outlier. I'm still not exactly sure what you find surprising or contradictory about these plots.